# A question on the twisted symmetric square L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Sorry to disturb. I have a puzzle which might be naive for many experts here.

Let $f$ be a Hecke newform of prime level $N$ on $\mathrm{GL}_2$, and $
\chi$ a primitive character of square-free conductor $M$ with $(N,M)=1$. Then it is known that the analytic conductor of the symmetric square $L$-function $L(s,\operatorname{sym}^2f)$ is $N^2$. My question is whether or not the analytic conductor of the twisted symmetric square $L$-function $L(s,\operatorname{sym}^2f\otimes \chi)$ is $NM^3$?

Notice that it seems that the analytic conductor should be $N^2M^3$ since that the conductor of symmetric square $L$-function $L(s,\text{sym}^2f)$ is already $N^2$. But I searched Munshi's paper (see https://doi.org/10.1515/crelle-2012-0038), the beginning of the Introduction (the first paragraph) tells us that the analytic conductor should be $NM^3$, which might stem from the structure of its local $L$-factors.

If any expert here learns something on this, please give some comments or guide certain references. Many thanks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Munshi is wrong and you are right.

Comment: Does $f$ have trivial character here? If the character of $f$ is trivial (so $f$ is locally of Steinberg type at p) then you are right. If the character of $f$ is non-trivial quadratic (and I think in only that case) then Munshi's formula is correct.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler  Yes, $f$ is of trivial nebentypus here.